# Change product sorting in Python ecommerce website

Tags: python, sorting

Not familiar with Pyton so any help is apreciated.
I have this e-commerce website developed in Python. On the category page I have a product sorting that organizez the products by the best selling products and the smallest prices via checbox. The point is that the best selling is the always first checked option and I want that the smallest price to be that one.

```
{% for (k,v) in constants.SORT_ENUM %}
<label class="radio-inline" style="color:{{ '#f00' if 
v==constants.SORT_CONST.PRETUL_CEL_MAI_MIC else '#333' }}">
<input type="radio" name="sortby" value="{{ v }}" onchange="if 
(this.checked){ document.cookie 
='sortby='+this.value+';path=/';document.location='{{ canonical_domain_url 
}}{{ context.request_url }}';}" {% if handler.get_sort_opt()==v %}checked{% 
end %}> {{ k }}
</label>
{% end %}
```

Comment: What templating engine is this?

Comment: Hi @Selcuk! I think it's called virtualenv. Just found a readme file that says that. Hope it's correct.

Comment: @danski virtualenv is not a templating engine. This looks vaguely like Jinja but with a few deviations.

Comment: I suppose you are trying to use javascript with Jinja Templating. But this would not help you achieve what you exactly want. i would suggest you to either receive presorted values from the backend as context variable or use REST too fetch the values and then use JavaScript to manipulate the order based on the user options.

Comment: Well I have the products that I want listed, but I want the checkbox with the lowest prices to be always selected first. Right now is the other now always selected first.